# Filter/grep functions behaving oddly

Tags: regex, r

Take the following code to select only alphanumeric strings from a list of strings:

```
isValid = function(string){
  return(grep("^[A-z0-9]+$", string))
}

strings = c("aaa", "test@test.com", "", "valid")

print(Filter(isValid, strings))
```

The output is `[1] "aaa"           "test@test.com"`.

Why is `"valid"` not outputted, and why is `"test@test.com"` outputted?

Comment: So the logic is, if there is any non alphanumeric code then do not output the string?

Comment: No, the point is that you need to use `[A-Za-z0-9]`, but I see it still does not work then.

Comment: Use `strings[grepl("^[[:alnum:]]+$", strings)]`

Comment: `return(grep("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$", strings, value=TRUE))` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 5):

The `Filter` function accepts a logical vector, you supplied a numeric. Use `grepl`:

```
isValid = function(string){
  return(grepl("^[A-z0-9]+$", string))
}

strings = c("aaa", "test@test.com", "", "valid")

print(Filter(isValid, strings))
[1] "aaa"   "valid"
```

Why didn't `grep` work? It is due to R's coercion of numeric values to logical and the weirdness of `Filter`.

Here's what happened, `grep("^[A-z0-9]+$", string)` correctly returns `1 4`. That is the index of matches on the first and fourth elements.

But that is not how `Filter` works. It runs the condition on each element with `as.logical(unlist(lapply(x, f)))`.

So it ran `isValid(strings[1])` then `isValid(strings[2])` and so on. It created this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
integer(0)

[[4]]
[1] 1
```

It then called `unlist` on that list to get `1 1` and turned that into a logical vector `TRUE TRUE`. So in the end you got:

```
strings[which(c(TRUE, TRUE))]
```

which turned into

```
strings[c(1,2)]
[1] "aaa"           "test@test.com"
```

Moral of the story, don't use `Filter` :)

Answer (score 2):

You could go the opposite direction with this and exclude any strings with punctuation, i.e.

```
isValid <- function(string){
  v1 <- string[!string %in% grep('[[:punct:]]', string, value = TRUE)] 
  return(v1[v1 != ''])
  }
isValid(strings)
#[1] "aaa"   "valid"
```